# Algebraically simplify expressions with -1 raised to a power

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have $2(-1)^{n-2} + (-1)^{n-1}$.

I can intuitively deduce that this simplifies to $(-1)^{n}$. How can I reach the simplified form algebraically?

Comment: $(-1)^{n-2}=(-1)^{n}$ and $(-1)^{n-1}=-(-1)^{n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example like this:

$$2(-1)^{n-2} + (-1)^{n-1} = 2(-1)^{n-2} - (-1)^{n-2} = (2-1)(-1)^{n-2} = (-1)^{n}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$(-1)^{n -1}=-(-1)^n.$$